# After Form submit does not get filename

Tags: forms

I am trying submit a form which is dynamically generated. 
After form submit i get all the values from `Form` except one element which is file element.
Even my form enctype is `multipart/form-data`.

I checked with `HTTPfox` it is showing below

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upfile1"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

I don't understand what is going on here.

```
       var str_new='<form id="uploader'+count+'" action="testkal.php" name="frmattach_kal" class="uploader" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target'+count+'"><div id="upload_progress_form'+count+'" style="clear:both">&nbsp;</div>';
       str_new +='<div class="upload_form" id="f'+count+'_upload_form"><div class="attch rmailsprite"></div><div class="upld" id="upld"><div id="upl'+count+'" class="zin2" style="width:62px;overflow:hidden;cursor:pointer;float:left;position:absolute;filter: alpha(opacity=0);"><input id="myfile'+count+'" name="upfile1" type="file" class="fileclass" size="30" onchange="javascript:upload_form_attachment('+count+');" /><input type=hidden name="FormName" value="attach" /><input type=hidden name="output" value="xml" /><input type=hidden name="sid" value="5" /></div>';
        str_new +='<div class="cornLeftTop" style="float:left;"><a id="anch'+count+'" style="text-decoration: underline;" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:test_fn('+count+');">Select file</a><span class="greyI" id="upld_inst'+count+'">(This file will start attaching once the previous file is done)</span></div>';
        str_new +='</div><div class="adjustdiv"></div></form><iframe id="upload_target'+count+'" name="upload_target'+count+'" class="upload_target" src=""></iframe>';
        document.getElementById("uploadstate").innerHTML=str_new;
```

This is how i am generating form.It is getting submitted onchange event of file element.
           document.getElementById("uploader"+count).setAttribute("enctype","multipart/form-data");
         document.getElementById("uploader"+count).setAttribute("encoding","multipart/form-data");

I am also setting enctype here

Comment: What are you using the process the submitted form?

Comment: its much usefull if you post the whole code that leads to submission.

Comment: I am uploading file through ajax. I am submitting form by javascript.

Comment: I updated the question now with code